# How to Set a Child to Parent Relationship in Visio?

Tags: parent-child, visio, cardinality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r8OI.png)So I'm being asked to make a Crows Foot diagram for the following rule.
   "A painter can paint many paintings. Each painting is painted by only one painter."

So I created 2 entities painters and paintings, and created a relationship between the two, with painters being the parent and paintings being the child. I set the cardinality to zero or more to represent A painter can paint many paintings, but I do not know how to set another relationship from child to parent to represent that Each painting is painted by only one painter. Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: Which version of Visio you are using ?

Comment: Using Visio 2010.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of you current problem in your question ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add attachments on here, but the whole problem is "A painter can paint many paintings. Each painting is painted by only one painter." So I created 2 entities painters and paintings, created a relationship between the two with painters being the parent and paintings being the child, and paints being the verb phrase. There is a section to set the Parent to child relationship cardinality but not one for child to parent cardinality.

Comment: Edit your question and add image from the toolbar shown at the top of textbox. Your problem is tool specific not DB specific

Comment: Okay, just added one of what I'm looking at.

Comment: The thing you are asking is already done for you. I know you want to do it yourself but visio 2010 does not offer that. I don't know why. I came across a solution but its not a proper solution. If you want I can post that as answer.

Comment: Okay, so is there no way to set a child to parent cardinality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem and unfortunately MS Visio 2010 does not offer this functionality of setting child to parent cardinality.

I found a solution (Maybe its the official provided way) by searching on the internet and on my own.

Steps

- First set the usual relationship connector to both entities. So that
  the child entity gets a foreign key **FK#** label with the foreign key
- select the relationship line and delete it.
- It will ask **if you want to delete underlying data object** (something
  like that) as well. Click **NO**.
- There is a **dynamic connector** as well with other diagrams in toolbox. Drag it on page.
- **Right click** the connector and Click **Format -> Line**.
- In that dialog, there are options of starting and ending line styles at the right top panel.
- Set the desired styles (and size if you want).
- Click **OK**
- Join each end with desired entities.
- The foriegn key attribute might not be bold.
- Click **Entity** and Go to **Columns** and make that Foriegn key column **"Required"**

Maybe this is a hacky solution but it does the work

Answer (score 0):

On the child table (Paintings) make the foreign key "Required" and this should change the child-to-parent cardinality